# Cabal - add build dependency with Cabal instead of manually mangling with the file

Tags: haskell, cabal

Do I need to manually edit the *.cabal file's `build-depends` section to add package as a project dependency?
Or perhaps there is a more convenient way that is not as error prone as manually mangling with build files is.

Thinking about functionality that pretty much any package manager I used has, namely

`apt install`

`npm i`

`nuget install`

`Install Package`

and so on. Does such functionality exist in Cabal?

Comment: Well, `apt install` etc. aren't really comparable. It _used_ to be possible to `cabal install` a package to the “global project” and then it would be available in any Haskell file without an associated cabal project... but eventually people agreed that this was unreliable, and that explicitly adding dependencies to the `.cabal` file is actually the _better_ way. That said, I agree that it would be nice to have a command-line utility for the actual editing of the file, including lookup of a suitable version range.

Comment: That functionality is not supported in `cabal-install` itself. There's a helper executable called `cabal-edit` that seems to do what you want. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-edit You can install it with the command `cabal install cabal-edit --overwrite-policy=always --install-method=copy --installdir=some_destination_folder`.

Comment: When you type `apt install whatever-fancy-program` and `apt` tells you it's also going to install `gtk`, how do you suppose it knows that `gtk` is a dependency? Answer: somebody manually mangled a file to record that information. (And if this is not the functionality that you refer to when you say "such functionality", then can you be more specific about what you want? You may think it's obvious, but to me it's not -- I'm making a lot of guesses here.)

Comment: @DanielWagner You are answering a question that I did not ask. Too big gun. @dandiaz gave me a good pointer that is still something but nowhere near to succinctness of `npm i` See, what I am looking for is just a way to use package manager to add build dependencies in the cabal file. Just that. Currently I need to do that manually which is surprising and I guess more experienced Haskell programmers do have a better way to manage build dependencies other that typing them manually. At least I hope this is the case.

Comment: I am pretty sure most experienced Haskell programmers just write their dependencies in their cabal files. Usually the time spent adding dependencies is negligible compared to the total time spent on a project. I am not very familiar with npm but maybe it is also a difference of philosophy because packages on npm are smaller compared to packages of other languages? Then time spent on modifying metadata might start becoming significant.

Answer (score 4):

There is no better way at the moment. The answer @danidiaz gave is essentially correct -- `cabal-edit` will automatically update cabal files for you. The plan is to import similar functionality into cabal directly. This was remains blocked on an exactprinter that can parse and emit cabal files precisely -- and work on that exactprinter is now underway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subcommand [`cabal gen-bounds`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-commands.html#cabal-gen-bounds) which is a bit more convenient but not such enough.

Just declare your dependencies without version tag in `.cabal` file. And then run `cabal gen-bounds` and manually copy the output into the `.cabal`.